# Typescript string empty check is not working

Tags: typescript

how to validate white space to false. am using  `if (value)` to check `value`. `method2` prints true. is there any method to check  white space string like this `'  '`

```
 method1() {
    this.method2(' ');
  }

  method2(value) {
    debugger;
    if (value) {
      console.log("true");
    } else {
      console.log("false");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Because it's not really empty. There is a whitespace

Comment: updated question

Comment: You're not checking whether a string is empty, you're just checking whether it is _truthy_. In JavaScript (and by extension, TypeScript), a string containing one space is considered to be _true_.

Answer (score 1):

The string isn't really empty. There is a whitespace.

You could check for `Null` and `Whitespace` like that:

```
function isEmpty(input){
    return (input.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0 ? false : true);
}
```

Using the code like this:

```
method2(value) {
    //...
    if (!isEmpty(value)) {
        console.log("true");
    } else {
        console.log("false");
    }
}
```